# Forge viewer does not respect the up direction of some Inventor models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are having an issue with some Inventor models, where the orientation and up direction in the forge viewer does not match the home view within Inventor.

This screenshot is of a sample model in Inventor (home view):
[cylinder pointing upwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8o7y.png)

This screenshot shows how it is displayed in the viewer:
[cylinder on it's side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg0b9.png)

We are creating the svf file directly from Inventor design automation, in exactly the same way as the forge configurator sample https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor

Is there anything that we need to do explicitly to have the viewer use the home view and up direction from the Inventor model?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have now found the answer to my own question!

In the svf exporter I had turned off the option to export file properties:

```
oOptions.set_Value("ExportFileProperties", false);
```

Thinking that this would just eliminate the part properties, but it seems like it must remove the up direction and home view also.

Comment: Well done on figuring that out. It's difficult to list everything a given option might affect   "Boolean value, indicates whether export the file properties to SVF or not. The default is True." does not say what the actual effects of this option might be.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I have a model where I also set a custom orientation as Front and as Home then exported to SVF with ExportFileProperties=false, but both the model orientation and the cube labels seem correct. I'm testing in Inventor 2022.2.2
Could you please provide a sample model?

Comment: Thanks @adam-nagy, I have sent you an email with a sample model.